# How to give a different name to a register in GNU ARM assembler?

Tags: assembly, arm, c-preprocessor, gnu, preprocessor-directive

I have [tiva c TM4C123GH6PM](http://www.ti.com/product/tm4c123gh6pm) and I have just installed a GNU ARM tool chain. I want to program only in assembly, because I would like to a build FORTH system for it, but when I use

```
.equ  W, r2             // working register
```

this gives a symbol r2

```
add W, IP, #4
main.S(54): error: undefined symbol r2 used as an immediate value
```

then I changed to:

```
#define W r2
```

now gives

```
add W, IP, #4
main.S(55): error: undefined symbol W used as an immediate value
```

Questions:

- Is it possible to change the name?
- If not, can I use a C predecessor for that?

Comment: I used GCC with -x assembler-with-cpp, but I can't make KEIL use it, so I switched to code-blocks, but again  can't put link script with code-blocks!
any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To create an alias for a register, use [`.req`](https://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html#ARM-Directives):

```
W .req r2
...
add W, IP, #4
```

Comment: AMAZING. I was using that [Assembler Directives](https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/old-gnu/Manuals/gas-2.9.1/html_chapter/as_7.html). thanks man :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't rename the registers.

To use the preprocessor you need to compile with GCC and not with `as`. Apart from using `arm-none-eabi-cpp` directly, there are two ways to do it:

- Name your assembly file with a `.S` (*uppercase*) extension and compile with GCC (e.g. `arm-none-eabi-gcc -c foo.S -o foo.o`). A *lowercase* `.s` extension would skip preprocessing.
- Name your assembly file whatever you want and pass `-x assembler-with-cpp` to GCC (e.g. `arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -x assembler-with-cpp foo.bar -o foo.o`. Using `-x assembler` instead skips preprocessing.

If you're compiling with Keil use the `.sx` extension (listed [here](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124196340.htm)). I couldn't find a switch like GCC's `-x`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I gave it to Notlikethat as his method doesn't use predecessor, both methods worked .sx and .req

thanks again.